# Generic requiring in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently working on a small personal multiplayer game project. I am using node.js along with express.js, mongoose and socket.io. It is my first project with JavaScript, I come from a C/C++ background.

The question is:
Whether some kind of generic requiring is possible:
I have currently a models folder in my project root and all the mongoose models are in there,
they all look similar to this one:

```
function make(Schema, mongoose) {
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name      : String
  , passwd    : String
  , is_online : Boolean
  , socket_id : Number
});
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
}
module.exports.make = make;
```

If I remember right, I found this approach somewhere on stackoverflow. Now when I am starting the node.js application, I have to connect to the database and then have to call all the make functions.

Is there a generic way to do that?

Somethink like this (pseudo-code):

```
models = require('./models/');
for each m in models do
{
     m.make(Schema, mongoose);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it a little different:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name      : String
  , passwd    : String
  , is_online : Boolean
  , socket_id : Number
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Now I can require the model and use it right away like this:

```
var userModel = require('models/user');
userModel.find()//...
```